# Simple tool to 'accept theirs' or 'accept mine' on a whole file using git

Tags: git, merge

I don't want a visual merge tool, and I also don't want to have to vi the conflicted file and manually choose the between HEAD (mine) and the imported change (theirs).  Most of the time I either want all of their changes or all of mine.  Commonly this is because my change made it upsteam and is coming back to me through a pull, but may be slightly modified in various places.

Is there a command line tool which will get rid of the conflict markers and choose all one way or another based on my choice?  Or a set of git commands which I can alias myself to do each one.

```
# accept mine
alias am="some_sequence;of;commands"
alias at="some_other_sequence;of;commands"
```

Doing this is rather annoying.
For 'accept mine' I have tried:

```
randy@sabotage ~/linus $ git merge test-branch
Auto-merging Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Makefile
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

randy@sabotage ~/linus $ git checkout Makefile 
error: path 'Makefile' is unmerged

andy@sabotage ~/linus $ git reset --hard HEAD Makefile 
fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.
```

How am I supposed to get rid of these change markers?

I can do:

```
git reset HEAD Makefile; rm Makefile; git checkout Makefile
```

But this seems rather round about, there must be a better way.  And at this point, I'm not sure if git even thinks the merge happened, so I don't think this necessarily even works.

Going the other way, doing 'accept theirs' is equally messy.
The only way I can figure it out is do:

```
git show test-branch:Makefile > Makefile; git add Makefile;
```

This also gives me a messed up commit message, which has Conflicts: Makefile in it twice.

Can someone please point out how to do the above two actions in a simpler way?  Thanks

Comment: I have to give it to you as a three year+ git command line user I find this ridiculously hard to do from memory.  It really should be built in by default.

Answer (score 739, accepted):

The solution is very simple. `git checkout <filename>` tries to check out file from **the index**, and therefore fails on merge.

What you need to do is (i.e. checkout a **commit**):

**To checkout your own version** you can use *one* of:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <filename>
```

or

```
git checkout --ours -- <filename>
```

(Warning!: If you are rebasing  `--ours` and `--theirs` are swapped.)

or

```
git show :2:<filename> > <filename> # (stage 2 is ours)
```

**To checkout the other version** you can use *one* of:

```
git checkout test-branch -- <filename>
```

or

```
git checkout --theirs -- <filename>
```

or

```
git show :3:<filename> > <filename> # (stage 3 is theirs)
```

You would also need to run 'add' to mark it as resolved:

```
git add <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll add that these flags are very new, they aren't in 1.6.0 which is what I was using from source (and distro's like Ubuntu have even older versions of Git)

Comment: I found it a bit strange that `--ours` and `--theirs` means exactly the opposite of what I intuitively thought when trying out this command...

Comment: Be careful when using `git show` – this skips newline normalization.

Comment: This is nice for a few files, but when you have many files in conflict (because a date in a comment was changed!), how do you do it ?

Comment: These are great, I'm assuming we would use these after we see the merge conflicts.  But what if I know I always want to accept the "theirs" version of the files, can I do it in the merge command?  I tried git merge -X theirs however it accepts their version of each conflict, rather than accepting their file as a whole when there is an issue.

Comment: I'm confused.. I'm on Windows (no, that's not why I'm confused!) ;-)  I get an error when I run `git show :3:filename`..  The only way I have been able to accept the server file is by typing `git checkout BRANCH_MERGED_IN -- file`.. Is this not correct? I tried `git checkout --theirs -- file` and nothing happens..

Comment: @wasatchwizard: what is the error message? I guess that the problem might be with `:3:` be similar to `C:`...

Comment: @JakubNarębski it seems that the `git show :n:file` command does not work in Windows!? I am not certain I fully understand the `:n:file` part, but I can't get it to do anything, except an error (also tried 1 and 2): `> git show :3:css\myfile.css
fatal: Path 'css\myfile.css' does not exist (neither on disk nor in the index)`. The good news is that the first command does work just fine.

Comment: @JakubNarębski after reading the docs again (painful, I know) I tried a few other things. Turns out, that in order to use the `:n:` syntax I must use the full or relative (linux-style with preceding '.') path in the command and I have to use forward-slashes also. for instance: `> git show :3:./css/myfile.css` works! I can redirect/pipe it to the same filename as in the example or whatever.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @wasatchwizard did you try `git show ':3:css/style.css'` (slash not backslash)?

Comment: @wasatchwizard `:` is the conventional way to select a "stream" on NTFS.  NTFS files can have arbitrary streams, essentially, an NTFS file is a little directory which, if you open it as a file, opens a default file within it for you instead.

Comment: What are the self standing --?

Comment: @Santhos: the `--` is used by Git to separate revisions (branch names etc.) from path names (filenames, directories).  It is important if Git cannot decide if a name is the name of branch or the name of file.  This follows POSIX (or GNU) convention of using double dash to separate options from arguments (filenames).

Comment: To clarify, "checkout --ours" keeps our changes and rejects theirs.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Can you clarify what you meant that --ours and --theirs have the opposite to expected results?  Maybe my expectations are different, but I'm also not clear whether I'm just missing something...

Comment: Really confused by what @JoshuaMuheim pointed out in his comment. What is the logic here? I've felt on numerous occasions like git has had its perspective switched. Does anyone think this makes sense? An explanation would be lovely and make my brain less foggy.

Comment: `git checkout test-branch -- <filename>` was useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Sammaron @Joshua Muheim; the `theirs`/`ours` can appear swapped if you are resolving conflicts in the context of a rebase operation. Because rebase works by checking out the target branch then cherry-picking commits from "your" branch onto the target, the incoming  change ("theirs") is from "your" branch, and the current branch is the target branch ("ours").

Comment: thank the lord i read @JoshuaMuheim comment before committing anything

Comment: this works well as well with folders, ie: `git checkout --ours  html/`

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim me too at first, but it makes sense when you think about 'LOCAL' or '--ours' always being the base branch, i.e. the branch you merge into or the branch you are rebasing onto. So the feature  branch or testing branch can always be viewed as 'the other' branch

Answer (score 158):

Try this:

- To accept **their** changes: `git merge --strategy-option theirs`
- To accept **your** changes: `git merge --strategy-option ours`

Comment: Note that this will keep your changes for ALL conflicting files, so could be dangerous if an unexpected conflict occurs.

Comment: And you can use this for other merge-y commands like cherry-pick and rebase.

Comment: Is there any way you can specify a directory in which you want only `theirs`, but manually resolve the conflicts otherwise? Ex: `git merge --strategy-option theirs some/dir`. So, if a conflict is in a file from path `some/dir`, then accept theirs, but if it is not, then ask me?

Comment: Question posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623581/how-do-i-accept-git-merge-conflicts-from-their-branch-for-only-a-certain-direc

Comment: I am having `fatal: No current branch.`

Comment: error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Answer (score 57):

Based on Jakub's answer you can configure the following git aliases for convenience:

```
accept-ours = "!f() { git checkout --ours -- \"${@:-.}\"; git add -u \"${@:-.}\"; }; f"
accept-theirs = "!f() { git checkout --theirs -- \"${@:-.}\"; git add -u \"${@:-.}\"; }; f"
```

They optionally take one or several paths of files to resolve and default to resolving everything under the current directory if none are given.

Add them to the `[alias]` section of your `~/.gitconfig` or run

```
git config --global alias.accept-ours '!f() { git checkout --ours -- "${@:-.}"; git add -u "${@:-.}"; }; f'
git config --global alias.accept-theirs '!f() { git checkout --theirs -- "${@:-.}"; git add -u "${@:-.}"; }; f'
```

Comment: Not working for me... Are these for bash or some other shell?

Comment: These are git aliases, add them to the `[alias]` section in your `~.gitconfig` or use `git config --global accept-ours "..."`. Have edited my answer.

Comment: You have no idea how much time this alias saved me.  Thumbs up!

Comment: Tried the first `git config --global accept-ours ...` command and got: *"sh: !f: event not found"*. Just some feedback.

Comment: @hakre Make sure you quote the alias, otherwise your shell will try to interpret it. Or just manually edit your `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: @kynan: Yes, I then edited the config. Not so well with shell quoting but I'm getting better :)

Comment: I copied the first two into `git config -e` and i got an error `expecting binary operator` -- I'm on MacOSX does this make a diff?

Comment: @qodeninja You'll want to use `git config --global -e` or you will edit the repo local configuration. Also make sure it's in the `[alias]` section.

Comment: @kynan thank you for the info -- the problem was with the syntax. shell logic statements need to have double brackets [[ ]] instead of []

Comment: @qodeninja depends on your system and shell: `[[` is a shell builtin, whereas `[` is a binary (which might not be available on OSX).

Comment: I added a couple DOSKEY macros to my Windows machine to accomplish the same thing. Here is ours: `git-ours=git checkout --ours $* & git add -u $*` and here is theirs: `git-theirs=git checkout --theirs $* & git add -u $*`. Maybe it'll help others.. As a side note, the git-theirs works for (and is shorter to type than) `git checkout -- file` to undo changes.

Comment: Shell syntax for default values: `!f() { git checkout --ours -- "${@:-.}" git add -u "${@:-.}; }; f`

Comment: this does not seem to be working with zsh on OS X.  getting `zsh: event not found: f()`

Comment: @wprater Seems your shell is interpreting the `!` as a history substitution. I've fixed it using `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @kynan with single quotes, it complains about unclose quotes now.  `accept-ours = '!f() { git checkout --ours -- "${@:-.}"; git add -u "${@:-.}"; }; f'`

Comment: @wprater sorry, I don't use `zsh` so can't verify but I can't see an unclosed quote there.

Comment: @kynan Should the aliases use double hyphens to indicate filenames follow: `git add -u --` (it's on the checkout, but not add)? (Originally suggested by @Dar's answer.)

Answer (score 19):

Based on kynan's answer, here are the same aliases, modified so they can handle spaces and initial dashes in filenames:

```
accept-ours = "!f() { [ -z \"$@\" ] && set - '.'; git checkout --ours -- \"$@\"; git add -u -- \"$@\"; }; f"
accept-theirs = "!f() { [ -z \"$@\" ] && set - '.'; git checkout --theirs -- \"$@\"; git add -u -- \"$@\"; }; f"
```

Comment: Please, write the answer that are helpful for the other people.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal situation for resolving conflicts is when you know ahead of time which way you want to resolve them and can pass the `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` recursive merge strategy options.  Outside of this I can see three scenarious:

1. You want to just keep a single version of the file (this should probably only be used on unmergeable binary files, since otherwise conflicted and non-conflicted files may get out of sync with each other).
2. You want to simply decide all of the conflicts in a particular direction.
3. You need to resolve some conflicts manually and then resolve all of the rest in a particular direction.

To address these three scenarios you can add the following lines to your `.gitconfig` file (or equivalent):

```
[merge]
  conflictstyle = diff3
[mergetool.getours]
  cmd = git-checkout --ours ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.mergeours]
  cmd = git-merge-file --ours ${LOCAL} ${BASE} ${REMOTE} -p > ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.keepours]
  cmd = sed -i '' -e '/^<<<<<<</d' -e '/^|||||||/,/^>>>>>>>/d' ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.gettheirs]
  cmd = git-checkout --theirs ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.mergetheirs]
  cmd = git-merge-file --theirs ${LOCAL} ${BASE} ${REMOTE} -p > ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.keeptheirs]
  cmd = sed -i '' -e '/^<<<<<<</,/^=======/d' -e '/^>>>>>>>/d' ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
```

The `get(ours|theirs)` tool just keeps the respective version of the file and throws away all of the changes from the other version (so no merging occurs).

The `merge(ours|theirs)` tool re-does the three way merge from the local, base, and remote versions of the file, choosing to resolve conflicts in the given direction.  This has some caveats, specifically: it ignores the diff options that were passed to the merge command (such as algorithm and whitespace handling); does the merge cleanly from the original files (so any manual changes to the file are discarded, which could be good or bad); and has the advantage that it cannot be confused by diff markers that are supposed to be in the file.

The `keep(ours|theirs)` tool simply edits out the diff markers and enclosed sections, detecting them by regular expression.  This has the advantage that it preserves the diff options from the merge command and allows you to resolve some conflicts by hand and then automatically resolve the rest.  It has the disadvantage that if there are other conflict markers in the file it could get confused.

These are all used by running `git mergetool -t (get|merge|keep)(ours|theirs) [<filename>]` where if `<filename>` is not supplied it processes all conflicted files.

Generally speaking, assuming you know there are no diff markers to confuse the regular expression, the `keep*` variants of the command are the most powerful.  If you leave the `mergetool.keepBackup` option unset or true then after the merge you can diff the `*.orig` file against the result of the merge to check that it makes sense.  As an example, I run the following after the `mergetool` just to inspect the changes before committing:

```sh
for f in `find . -name '*.orig'`; do vimdiff $f ${f%.orig}; done
```

**Note**: If the `merge.conflictstyle` is not `diff3` then the `/^|||||||/` pattern in the `sed` rule needs to be `/^=======/` instead.

Comment: What is sed -I ''? This does not exist on my system.

Comment: @simohe try `sed -i ''` instead. It just allows for in-place editing. I should have used lowercase anyway so I’ll update the post.