# Choose Git merge strategy for specific files ("ours", "mine", "theirs")

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I am in the middle of rebasing after a `git pull --rebase`.  I have a few files that have merge conflicts.  How can I accept "their" changes or "my" changes for specific files?

```
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# You are currently rebasing.
#   (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
#   (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
#   (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:  CorrectlyMergedFile
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified: FileWhereIWantToAcceptTheirChanges
#       both modified: FileWhereIWantToAcceptMyChanges
```

Normally I just open the file or a merge tool and manually accept all "their" or "my" changes.  However, I suspect I'm missing a convenient git command.

Also, note that I will only be able to choose a merge strategy for each file when I see what files hit conflicts an possibly what the conflicts are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple tool to 'accept theirs' or 'accept mine' on a whole file using git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914939/simple-tool-to-accept-theirs-or-accept-mine-on-a-whole-file-using-git).

Comment: FWIW: I came here trying to somehow undo a poor rebase of MR/PR branch with main. While `git checkout --ours origin/mr-pr-branch` worked it resulted in hundreds of commits to push. In the end checked out to main, deleted local mr-pr-branch, and pulled/checked-out again.

Answer (score 412, accepted):

For each conflicted file you get, you can specify

```
git checkout --ours -- <paths>
# or
git checkout --theirs -- <paths>
```

From the [`git checkout` docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> `git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...`
>
> **`--ours`**
>   **`--theirs`**
>   When checking out paths from the index, check out stage #2 (`ours`) or #3 (`theirs`) for unmerged paths.
>
> The index may contain unmerged entries because of a previous failed merge. By default, if you try to check out such an entry from the index, the checkout operation will fail and nothing will be checked out. Using `-f` will ignore these unmerged entries. The contents from a specific side of the merge can be checked out of the index by using `--ours` or `--theirs`. With `-m`, changes made to the working tree file can be discarded to re-create the original conflicted merge result.

Comment: Is it possible to accept theires for all files that are left umerged?

Comment: @aslakjo `git rebase -s recursive -X <ours/theirs>` or `git merge -s recursive -X <ours/theirs>`. Keep in mind that for a rebase, "ours" and "theirs" are reversed from what they are during a merge. You could probably just use a file/shell glob too, like `git checkout --theirs -- *.txt`.

Comment: This command does not work when <paths> is a submodule it seems.

Comment: Many thanks, @Cupcake, the unexpected reversal of `ours/theirs` with rebase was driving me crazy!! (It makes sense now that I think about how a rebase actually works, but not at all intuitive.)

Comment: @DanLenski rebase in general is just a really tricky tool for people to understand at first, but once you do understand how it works, you can do all kinds of really powerful things with it.

Comment: Yeah, I like to think of myself as somewhat of an expert user of `rebase`, but I'm embarrassed to say I had never figured out the reversal of `ours`/`theirs` and would always do these "the hard way" (commit by commit) until I read this.

Comment: On Windows using Git Bash, I needed to use /\ (forward slash, backward slash) as path separator, e.g. `git checkout --ours -- **/\*.csproj`. I have no idea why and can't find an answer on Google. Can anyone point me to an explanation? Using anything else fails; I tried. `*.csproj`, `**/*.csproj`, `**\/*.csproj`.

Comment: I do this, then git add, then rebase --continue, and I find myself in the same situation again, can't get out of the loop.

Comment: somehow, git checkout has no effect on the staged files for me

Comment: @VincentSels actually, you need to mask the * character, else, the shell will try to expand it. so in your case `git checkout --outs -- "**/*.csproj"` will do what you mean. The same is true e.g. for `git lfs track "*.jpg"`. If you have some jpg-files in your CWD, without the quotes, only these would be tracked.

Comment: @TinMan git is very quiet when using `git checkout --ours/--theirs -- <path>`. Make sure you do a `git add <path>` afterwards, then you'll see the results you're looking for

Comment: **BEWARE**, using `checkout [--ours|--theirs] -- file` will *completely overwrite* the `file` with either: the one from our branch, or the one from the branch being merged. This is somehow dangerous as you may have correctly merged chunks on the `file` that you will discard! What you want is applying the `ours` or `theirs` strategy *only on the conflicting chunks* within the file! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126509/how-to-resolve-git-merge-conflict-from-command-line-using-a-given-strategy-fo) or *jakub.g*'s for a solution considering this point.

Answer (score 234):

Even though this question is answered, providing an example as to what "theirs" and "ours" means in the case of git rebase vs merge. See [this link](https://demisx.github.io/git/rebase/2015/07/02/git-rebase-keep-my-branch-changes.html)

**Git Rebase**
`theirs` is actually the current branch in the case of *rebase*. So the below set of commands are actually accepting your current branch changes over the remote branch.

```
# see current branch
$ git branch
... 
* branch-a
# rebase preferring current branch changes during conflicts
$ git rebase -X theirs branch-b
```

**Git Merge**
For *merge*, the meaning of `theirs` and `ours` is reversed. So, to get the same effect during a *merge*, i.e., keep your current branch changes (`ours`) over the remote branch being merged (`theirs`).

```
# assuming branch-a is our current version
$ git merge -X ours branch-b  # <- ours: branch-a, theirs: branch-b
```

Comment: What about a git pull --rebase ?

Comment: I *think* this was really helpful since `ours` is 100% opposite what one would think. Ours is the branch we're rebasing onto... right? Bizarre as expected.

Comment: @DanRosenstark think of rebasing as: 1. switching to `branch-b` (this becomes ours) 2. running `git commit` the first (and subsequently the next) commit from `branch-a` (this becomes theirs) 3. repeat step 2 for every other commit 4. point `branch-a` to the last commit from step 3. 

This is how "theirs" and "ours" is interpreted

Comment: will it be helpful if we use the terms `current` – `ours` for rebase, and `current` – `theirs` for merge?

Answer (score 43):

Note that `git checkout --ours|--theirs` will *overwrite the files entirely*, by choosing either `theirs` or `ours` version, which might be or might not be what you want to do (if you have any non-conflicted changes coming from the other side, they will be lost).

If instead  you want to perform a three-way merge on the file, and only resolve the **conflicted hunks** using `--ours|--theirs`, while **keeping non-conflicted hunks** from both sides in place, you may want to resort to `git merge-file`; see details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126510/245966).

Comment: Regarding "non-conflicting changes" that will be lost - this refers to only the files where there are non-conflicting changes in specific lines else where in the same file, or all changes from all files in aligned histories?

Comment: @ktamlyn by "non-conflicting changes" I meant changes in the same file. For example, there are two changed hunks (parts) in `example.txt` in `ours` version, one is conflicted (also changed in the `theirs` revision), other is non-conflicted. If you do `git checkout --theirs example.txt`, it will just blindly read the whole file at `theirs` revision, and the non-conflicted part of the diff will be lost.

Comment: Thanks! This was a necessary clarification for me, even though "changes in the same file" makes the most sense in this context.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, well, although it doesn't really give an answer, but points out an important issue in the other proposed solution.

Comment: If you want to go back to the original conflicted file you can run `git checkout --merge <path>`.

Answer (score 19):

quoting @user456814 from comment above:

> `git rebase -s recursive -X <ours/theirs>`
> or
> `git merge -s recursive -X <ours/theirs>`
>
> Keep in mind that for a rebase, "ours" and "theirs" are reversed from
> what they are during a merge

@user456814 gave this useful answer in comments on the accepted answer way back in 2014. I'm surfacing it here as a community wiki to make it easier to find, evaluate, update, etc, since comments are limited in that respect.