# Git merge ignore conflict from one branch?

Tags: xcode, git

I have git setup with an xcode project. Inside that project is a .storyboard file which is a very long xml file.

This file causes many conflicts when merging, because when updating the layout all views can get a minor change in their position or size by sometimes only 1px.

I have some branches in my git.

When Im on my master branch and want to merge master with my Test branch i get around 30 conflicts in that particular file.

Because it looks like this when there is a conflict:

```
>>>>>> HEAD 
           <Some stuff />
======
           <Some stufff />
>>>>>> Test
```

Is it possible to remove all the conflicts from HEAD or the branch I merged with?

Comment: `git mergetool` then select `Master`

Comment: In source tree there's the option of `resolve using mine/theirs`. Not sure how it is on other GUIs.

Comment: @Thomas Dont I need to install something for that? I remember I did this before by some very simple method I found but I forgot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the conflict arrives there are three files created

1. File of branch in which you are says `ours` (master in your case)
2. File of branch you want to merge says `theirs` (test in your case)
3. File with all the conflicts

and you can do the followings

1. Keep master branch files using `git checkout --ours <file path>`
2. Keep test branch files using `git checkout --theirs <files path>`
3. Resolve the conflicts manually

You can read more about it

1. http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html
2. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout
3. [Choose Git merge strategy for specific files ("ours", "mine", "theirs")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825849/choose-git-merge-strategy-for-specific-files-ours-mine-theirs)

Comment: This seems to be what I forgot about, And if I only put a . in file path every file will ignore ours/theirs?

Comment: As I havn't try the `.`, you can try it yourself

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and come back with your accept