# Ignoring directories when using git pull

Tags: git, github, git-pull

:)

I have a production *nix server that gets the updated files from github using "git pull".

My problem is that there are outdated versions of some plugins in "app/code/community/", which would be pulled and would overwrite my local (up-to-date) files and folders.

I do not know how to tell git to just ignore this directory when I pull from github... Can anybody help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: commit your changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. `git pull` it will replace you {up-to-date} files with old
2. `git checkout --ours -- <filename>` to revert you files to your version
3. `git add and commit`

Hope this solves your problem!

For more details try going through: [Simple tool to 'accept theirs' or 'accept mine' on a whole file using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914939/simple-tool-to-accept-theirs-or-accept-mine-on-a-whole-file-using-git)

Happy Gitting!