# Possible to resolve Git conflict on single file using Ours / Theirs?

Tags: git, command-line, merge

I've found many instructions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere for resolving conflicts using the OURS/THEIRS dynamic, in cases where you simply want to overwrite one file with another (particularly binary files). However in almost every example I find, it's always been applied en masse to all conflicts, whereas I only want to apply it to a single conflicted file.

One supposed solution I found is to use the git mergetool command. However the mergetool is giving me issues, where I select "choose left" or "choose right" and nothing happens.

Regardless of mergetool though, I'd like to know anyway if there is a way to do this from the command line. I'm sure there is, and if anyone would let me know the command, or otherwise link me to the SO question I must not be finding, I'd appreciate it greatly.

I've also tried using...

git checkout --theirs PATH/TO/CONFLICTED/FILE

But then when I enter 'git status', it still shows the file as conflicted.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You will need to `git add` the final resolution, unless you use a different method to extract the "ours" or "theirs" version.

#### Long

Each merge tool is independent of Git (Git just runs them and lets them do their things) so for that particular sub-part of this question, you must consult the merge tool itself.

As for the `git checkout --ours` or `git checkout --theirs`, well, this is where what Git calls the *index* shows its full bit of complexity.  Remember that the index, which is otherwise kind of mysterious and is also called the *staging area* and sometimes the *cache*, is essentially where you and Git build up the *next commit you will make*.

When you run:

```
git merge <commit-or-branch-specifier>
```

Git finds *three* commits:

- One is your *current commit*, which is the one you're always working with at any given time, so that's not really special, except that you can refer to it by the name `HEAD` or the single character `@` (e.g., `git rev-parse HEAD` or `git rev-parse @` to get its hash ID).
- One is the commit you just named.  If you ran `git merge otherbranch`, you can run `git rev-parse otherbranch` to see what its commit hash ID is right now.  (Branch names have the property of *moving:* that is, the commit identified by a branch name right now is not necessarily as the commit identified by that name yesterday, or tomorrow.  This motion of branch names is how branches grow.)  Of course if you ran `git merge a123456`, the other commit, the one for `--theirs`, is hash ID `a123456`.
- The last commit is the *merge base*, which Git finds for you automatically.  It finds this commit by using the parent linkages from your commit and the other commit, to work backwards through both branches until it finds the appropriate point where the two branches first come back together.

Having found the three commits, Git runs, in effect:

```
git diff --find-renames <merge-base> <ours>    # see what we changed
git diff --find-renames <merge-base> <theirs>  # see what they changed
```

The merge process—*to merge* as a verb, as it were—consists of finding these three commits, doing the diff, and combining the changes.  You get a merge conflict when the two sets of changes affect the same lines.

In a file where there are no merge conflicts, Git puts the result into both your work-tree (as an ordinary file) and the index (as the special Git-form of the file, ready to be committed).  So for unconflicted files, there is generally nothing else you need to do.

When there's a merge conflict, though, Git does two unusual things: first, it writes the merge-conflicted version into the work-tree, so that you can edit it as a plain file.  Second, it writes into the index, not *one* version of the file, but *all three*: the merge base version, the "ours" version, and the "theirs" version.

Git calls these extra versions *higher stages*.  Stage number is the merge base, and there's no `--base` option to access it, but you can use `git show :1:path` to see it.  Stage number two is the "ours" version: there's `--ours` but you can also run `git show :2:path` to see it.  Stage number 3 is the "theirs" version, available through `git show :3:path`.  These three stages *replace* the normal stage-zero entry, which is now missing.

In fact, when you run `git mergetool`, what that does is find the three versions in the index, extract them into regular (non-Git-ified) files, and run the actual merge tool on those three files.  The merge tool is assumed to Do The Right Thing (whatever that turns out to be) to combine the three files into one merged file, after which `git mergetool` can run `git add` on the result.

From the command line, though—which is how I do my merges—you can just edit the work-tree file, with its conflict markers, and figure out what the right result is.  Write that out, `git add` the resulting file, and you're good, because `git add` notices that the file exists in the three-staged-versions form and erases those three versions, writing instead into stage number zero.

Once there's a stage zero (and no longer stages 1-3), the file is considered resolved.

Now, `git checkout --ours -- path` just tells Git: *Take the stage-2 version out of the index and put it into the work-tree.*  The version with `--theirs` tells Git to take the stage-3 version instead.  In both cases, the index, with its three staged versions, is left alone.  This *only* extracts from the index, to the work-tree.  (The `--` here is just in case the *`path`* part is, say, a file named `--theirs`.  If the file name doesn't resemble an option, you don't need the `--`.  It's kind of a good habit to use the `--` all the time, but most people don't.)

Since the index still has all three staged versions, the file is not yet resolved.  Running `git add` takes the work-tree file and puts it in slot zero, wiping out the 1-through-3 entries, and now the file is resolved.

Curiously, running `git checkout HEAD -- path` or `git checkout otherbranch -- path` causes the file to become resolved.  This is an artifact of Git letting the implementation dictate the interface: internally, when you use `git checkout name -- path`, Git has to first locate the Git form of the file in the given *`name`* (a commit hash or a name like `HEAD` or *`otherbranch`*).  Then it has to *copy* that Git form *into* the index ... and this copying wipes out the slot 1-3 entries, writing into the normal slot-zero entry.  Last, Git then extracts the (Git-form) file from index entry zero to the work-tree.

The side effect of this "write to index first, then extract from index to work-tree" is that if the file was in conflicted state—had stages 1-3 active—it's no longer conflicted!  Hence:

```
git checkout --ours -- file
```

*doesn't* resolve the file (because it extracts from index slot 2), but:

```
git checkout HEAD -- file
```

*does* resolve the file (because it extracts from the current commit, going to index slot 0, wiping out 1-3; *then* extracts from the slot 0 entry it just wrote).

**Edit, Jun 2022:** Since I wrote the above, Git acquired a new pair of commands, `git switch` and `git restore`, that *split up* the multiple different jobs that `git checkout` used to combine.  If your Git is version 2.23 or later, you might wish to use `git restore` rather than `git checkout` for extracting individual files.  (When using the old `git checkout`, it's too easy to invoke it the wrong way: even experienced Git users will sometimes mess up here.)  Still, the `--ours` and `--theirs` flags *to* `git restore` work the same way as with `git checkout`: they select slots 2 and 3 respectively, always, even during a rebase (see the Postscript below).

#### Postscript

The above describes the merge-as-a-verb process invoked by the `git merge` command.  Git's internal merge engines—"merge as a verb"—are also used by `git cherry-pick`, `git revert`, and `git rebase` (among others).  When using these, the "merge base" commit—the entity that fills slot 1—is picked via a different process, and the "ours" and "theirs" commits—the things that go into slots 2 and 3, as named by, e.g., `--ours` with `git checkout` or `git restore` for instance, aren't always straightforward.  I will leave the details for other StackOverflow questions-and-answers, as this is plenty to digest.

Comment: It's overwhelming explanation, but thanks :)

Comment: Amazing answer that allow me "understand" instead of "copy & past". Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe add a warning that ours is theirs and theirs is ours when rebasing instead of merging

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: it's more complicated than that: in rebase, `--theirs` is always "ours" but `--ours` is ... well, it's pretty confusing: on the *first* commit to be copied, `--ours` is definitely theirs. After that, `--ours` is also ours, as modified to fit theirs! I cover this in answers about rebase. This is one reason I prefer to refer to "index slot" here.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: I did, however, edit this a bit to mention Git 2.23 and the fact that things get squirrelly during rebasing (or cherry-picking or reverting).

Answer (score 0):

This is a (slightly) modified version of my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914939/simple-tool-to-accept-theirs-or-accept-mine-on-a-whole-file-using-git/56121618).

Whenever you want help merging a single file I find it is best to write a custom `mergetool` which does what you want.  To this end I propose adding the following lines to your `.gitconfig` file (or equivalent):

```
[merge]
  conflictstyle = diff3
[mergetool.getours]
  cmd = git-checkout --ours ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.mergeours]
  cmd = git-merge-file --ours ${LOCAL} ${BASE} ${REMOTE} -p > ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.keepours]
  cmd = sed -I '' -e '/^<<<<<<</d' -e '/^|||||||/,/^>>>>>>>/d' ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.gettheirs]
  cmd = git-checkout --theirs ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.mergetheirs]
  cmd = git-merge-file --theirs ${LOCAL} ${BASE} ${REMOTE} -p > ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
[mergetool.keeptheirs]
  cmd = sed -I '' -e '/^<<<<<<</,/^=======/d' -e '/^>>>>>>>/d' ${MERGED}
  trustExitCode = true
```

The `get(ours|theirs)` tool just keeps the respective version of the file and throws away all of the changes from the other version (so no merging occurs).  This is the method you request with regards to binary files.

The `merge(ours|theirs)` tool re-does the three way merge from the local, base, and remote versions of the file, choosing to resolve conflicts in the given direction.  This has some caveats, specifically: it ignores the diff options that were passed to the merge command (such as algorithm and whitespace handling); does the merge cleanly from the original files (so any manual changes to the file are discarded, which could be good or bad); and has the advantage that it cannot be confused by diff markers that are supposed to be in the file.

The `keep(ours|theirs)` tool simply edits out the diff markers and enclosed sections, detecting them by regular expression.  This has the advantage that it preserves the diff options from the merge command and allows you to resolve some conflicts by hand and then automatically resolve the rest.  It has the disadvantage that if there are other conflict markers in the file it could get confused.

These are all used by running `git mergetool -t (get|merge|keep)(ours|theirs) [<filename>]` where if `<filename>` is not supplied it processes all conflicted files.

Generally speaking, assuming you know there are no diff markers to confuse the regular expression (and you're not dealing with binary files which cannot be merged), the `keep*` variants of the command are the most powerful.  If you leave the `mergetool.keepBackup` option unset or true then after the merge you can diff the `*.orig` file against the result of the merge to check that it makes sense.  As an example, I run the following after the `mergetool` just to inspect the changes before committing:

```sh
for f in `find . -name '*.orig'`; do vimdiff $f ${f%.orig}; done
```

**Note**: If the `merge.conflictstyle` is not `diff3` then the `/^|||||||/` pattern in the `sed` rule needs to be `/^=======/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case where I had a branch based on main "feature/MyBranch". But first I wanted to do tests in develop, however I had conflicts with some files.

What I did was create a new branch based on "feature/MyBranch" and name it: "feature/MyBranchToDevelop".

Then I switched to that branch:

```
git checkout feature/MyBranchToDevelop
```

Later, I did merge with develop

```
git merge develop
```

I resolved the conflicts and made the commit that is generated when doing the merge:

```
Merge branch 'develop' into feature/MyBranchToDevelop
```

I made one more commit, of adjustments that I needed:

```
Fix conflict files
```

Then I generated the PR, and I had no problems. Leaving the "feature/MyBranch" branch intact, which I would then send to main

Comment: What dou you mean by "send to main"? Is "main" a third branch that comes here into play or is "develop" your main branch?

Comment: "main" is the productive branch and "feature/MyBranch" is the branch based on main. If it were a hotfix, the branch could go directly to main, however, since it is a feature, it first goes through other environments before being able to reach main.